# Facebook oauth with multiple subdomains

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

So when I do not hardcode my subdomain in the app 
(settings - advanced - Valid OAuth redirect URIs)
and I just provide my TLD (domain.com)
and I try to login from a subdomain (user1.domain.com)
I get this error, which seems counterintuitive.

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. 
>   **It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.**

So, since I develop for a website platform, and each user has (userslug.domain.com), I can't actually hard-code each of these urls. The error message makes it seem that what I'm doing is allowed (or must be subdomain), but unless I provide the user1.domain.com in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs, I get this error.

Can I set the redirect URI programmatically? I'm using the old PHP SDK for now, but I'll ditch it in a heartbeat if there's an another way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you fully filled out your App Settings (the main page). Specifically the "App Domains" field?

Comment: Yes I did, like I said, it works when I use website subdomain1.domain.com, and add subdomain1.domain.com, to the settings, but it does not work with subdomain2.domain.com when I've added domain.com to the settings.

Anyway, its all bunk as facebook doesn't allow what we were trying to do anymore.